# Resolve an IP from a specific DNS server in Python

Tags: python, dns

I want to resolve an IP to a hostname from a specific DNS server.

`socket.gethostbyaddr()` uses default DNS server. I need to resolve ip with specific DNS server.

I saw `dnspython` but do not know how to specify the DNS server to use for reverse lookup.

Comment: Although not a duplicate, you might want to check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957249/python-implementing-concurrent-dns-requests-pipelining).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/set-specific-dns-server-using-dns-resolver-pythondns)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import dns.resolver

dns.resolver.default_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answers = dns.resolver.query(<addr>, 'PTR')
for rdata in answers:
    print(rdata)
```

Comment: You need to install the pip package `dnspython` for this to work.